# Can I store SelectedItem property value of a Picker under a ListView in an array?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, picker

I am working with Xamarin ListView and Picker, trying to create an android app that calculates a student's GPA in one page(view).
I have a class `GPADetails` that takes care of the Picker properties. This class contains a "List"...

`public ObservableRangeCollection<string> UnitList{get;set;}`

...of units binded to the `ItemSource` of the Picker. it also contains a "property field"...

`private string selectedUnit=null;`

`public string SelectedUnit { get => selectedUnit;`

`set => SetProperty(ref selectedUnit, value); }`
...that is binded to the  `SelectedItem` property of the picker.

The ListView is being populated by binding a "List"...

`public ObservableRangeCollection<GPADetails> GPADetailsList {get;set;}`
...of multiple objects of type `GPADetails` class to the `ItemSource` of the ListView.(so that the user can pick different units for different subjects)
Here's the function that populates the listView

```
public void DisplayTemplates()

        {

            GPADetailsList.Clear();

            //Instantiates  template object equivalent to the number of courses

            for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(NumberOfCourses); i++)

            {

                GPADetailsList.Add(

                new GPADetails

                {

                    //initializing picker properties with picker items

                    UnitList = UnitItems,                    

                    SelectedUnit = null,                    

                    TemplateID = i,

                   

                });

                

            }

        }
```

Heres the Xaml of the ListView and the picker...
...

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding GPADetailsList}" SelectionMode="None" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout >

                                <Editor  Placeholder="Course Code" PlaceholderColor="White"                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                </Editor>

                                <Picker x:Name="PickerUnit" Title="Pick a Unit" TitleColor="white"

                                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"
ItemsSource="{Binding UnitList}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit, Mode=TwoWay }"
                                      >
                             </Picker>
                          </StackLayout>                      

                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

...

Now here's where I'm having problems. Each time the user selects a unit on the page, the `selectedItem` property of the picker is triggered. And the `SelectedUnit` property of the `GPADetails` class detects the property changed.
I want so store the `SelectedItem` of each Picker that is under the ListView in an array.
Using a property `TemplateID` of class `GPADetails`, I'm able to track which picker has been selected.
So I use `TemplateID` as the index of my array.
But I keep having problems because my C# is weak.

I tried doing this in the  `SelectedUnit` property in class `GPADetails` by using a condition in the set accessor and initializing the array at the selected index with the `selectedUnit`. Heres the code..

```
private string selectedUnit;

        public string SelectedUnit

        {

            get { return selectedUnit; }

            set

            {

                SetProperty(ref selectedUnit, value);

                if (selectedUnit != null)

                    SelectedUnitList[TemplateID] = selectedUnit;

            }

 

        }
```

But with that, i can only assign one value to the array, if i try to assign another, the previously assigned index goes back to the
default value, null.

P.S. I don't know if I asked this right, but any help would be appreciated, thanks dev fam...

Comment: you need to post more code so we understand the context of what you're doing.  Is `SelectedUnit` part of `GPADetails`?  What about `SelectedUnitList`?  Is that part of the same class, or is it supposed to live on the page's VM/Codebehind?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If previous value is going back to null, then you may be creating the array each time an item is picked. Put breakpoint on line that defines or initializes array. If that gets called more than once, then that is your problem. Define/initialize array earlier. Somewhere that is only called one time.

Comment: @Jason I'm using MVVM. I have a ViewModel(`GPACalculationViewmodel`) where everything is suppose to be done. But then I created the `GPADetails` class for the Picker properties. `SelectedUnit` is part of `GPADetails`. `SelectedUnitList` is the array still part of `GPADetails`

Comment: Again, you need to post a [mcve] that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete my origin post and the following is my new answer.

**Each instance created in **DisplayTemplate** is separated. That means each instance has a different SelectedUnitList. That's the reason why you can only set one picker value in SelectedUnitList.**

Here i give you some suggestions.

In your **GPADetails.cs**, add a new property, that's a dictionary named *SelectedUnitDict*.(Compare to *SelectedUnitList*, I prefer to use a dictionary as index of an array easily causes troubles):

```
public Dictionary<int,string> SelectedUnitDict { get; set; } //The key(int) is *TemplateID* and the value(string) is *SelectedItem*.
```

In your **GPACalculationViewmodel**, also create a property (i just use the same name for convenience):

```
public Dictionary<int, string> SelelctedUnitDict { get; set; }
```

and add a new line in the **DisplayTemplates** methods, that makes each instance of **GPADetails** get the same *SelectedUnitDict* in GPACalculationViewmodel.

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(NumberOfCourses); i++)
    {

        GPADetailsList.Add(

            new GPADetails

            {

                //initializing picker properties with picker items

                UnitList = UnitItems,                    

                SelectedUnit = null,                    

                TemplateID = i,

                // Add this new line
                SelelctedUnitDict = SelelctedUnitDict

            });
```

Finally, in **GPADetails.cs**, just like your code:

```
public string SelectedUnit
    {
        ...
        set
        {
            ...
            if (selectedUnit != null)
            {
                
                SelectedUnitDict[TemplateID] = selectedUnit;
            }

        } 
    }
```

That's worked for me. I can get the selectedItem of each picker in my *SelectedUnitDict* in **GPACalculationViewmodel**. The key is *TemplateID* and the value is *SelectedItem*.

Hope my answer could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the properties/events to interact with the `ListView` instead of relying in the observable property.

You can use `ItemSelected`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:interactiveListViewXaml.items}" ItemSelected="OnSelection" ItemTapped="OnTap" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" Refreshing="OnRefresh">
```

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UserInterface/ListView/Interactivity/interactivityListView/interactivityListView/Views/interactiveListViewXaml.xaml

About the implementation I'm not sure what `TemplateID` is or all this sentence `I want so store the SelectedItem of each Picker under the ListView in an array using a property` I don't understand it

Comment: I had made some adjustment to the question. I just want to Keep the List of picker selectedItems in an array, so that I can further make use of it. Thanks